# trying to copy data with memcpy, getting error "Access violation writing location"

Tags: c++

I'm getting error on second memcpy
memcpy(&check_user, &ZZZ, (int)&main - (int)&check_user);

"Unhandled exception at 0x72cc1f57 (msvcr100.dll) in 11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00f31000."

What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PASSWD "+++"
#define MAX_LEN 1023
#define MAX_CODE_SIZE (0x10 * 1024)
#define OFFSET_1 0x42
#define OFFSET_2 0x67

#define x_original_1 0xc01b0574
#define x_original_2 0x44681574
#define x_original_all 0x13D4C04B

#define x_crypt 0x66
using namespace std;

int check_user()
{
        char passwd[MAX_LEN];

        cout<< "enter password:";
        fgets(passwd, MAX_LEN, stdin);
        return ~strcmp(passwd, PASSWD);
}

int my_func()
{
        if (check_user())
        {
                cout<<"passwd ok\n";
        }
        else
        {
                cout<<"wrong passwd\n";
                exit(-1);
        }
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        int a, b = 0;
        #pragma pack(1)
        union f
        {
                char buf[MAX_CODE_SIZE];
                struct
                {
                        int local_var_1;
                        int local_var_2;
                        char gag_1[OFFSET_1 - sizeof(int) * 2];
                        int x_val_1;
                        char gag_2[OFFSET_2 - OFFSET_1 - sizeof(int)];
                        int x_val_2;
                };
        };
  union f ZZZ;

     memcpy(&ZZZ, &check_user, (int)&main - (int)&check_user);

        for (a = 0; a < (int)&main - (int)&check_user; a++)
        {
                (*(char *) ((int)&ZZZ + a)) ^= x_crypt;
        }

     memcpy(&check_user, &ZZZ, (int)&main - (int)&check_user);

        for (a = 0; a < (int)&main - (int)&check_user; a++)
        {
                b += *(int *)((int)&check_user + a);
        }
        if (b != x_original_all)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "-ERR: invalid CRC (%x)\n", b);
                return 0;
        }


        my_func();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  It's weird, but I think I get it.  You want some code to be "encrypted" via a XOR.

You're going to have to do this in a memory buffer you allocate yourself that is read-write and also executable.  On Windows you can achieve this with [`VirtualAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887(VS.85).aspx) .  On Unix you can use [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with `MAP_ANON`.  See the protection flags for either of these calls: again you want writable, executable memory.

Also, interacting directly with this via function pointers is kind of sketchy.  I think you should write some code, compile/assemble it, apply some kind of cypher, and put in your obfuscated code as a sequence of bytes.  Or something like that.

Did I mention this is a bad idea?

Comment: Its hellacious to debug, may not operate properly across many systems unless it is well tested, and makes people laugh at your security attempts :-)

Comment: @Aelynn - Well.  First, this will make your code less maintainable.  Second, you'll put a lot of work into the "cyphered" code and getting that working correctly, for very little benefit, using up time that you could be using doing something more constructive.  Lastly...  It doesn't really gain you anything.  If a hacker (or whoever) knows what they are doing, they will still figure out what's going on and be able to look at your code all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to the memory location of the function `check_user`.
The code of this function must reside in a read only memory location, where you are not allowed to write.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to &check_user, which is a function.

It is highly likely that the code-segment of your program is protected/read-only.

On old machines, writing to code-segments was possible, but dangerous.
Modern machines/OS's won't allow it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get "size" of a function using this "technique"

Answer (score 0):

As ssg wrote you can't expect copying code memory to work at all. Also, `(int)&main - (int)&check_user` is possibly a negative value as `main` is not guaranteed to be located above `check_user` in memory.

Comment: I always get positive number. But it doesn't mean that everything fine, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to create self-modifying code, you will need to place this code in a data section, and inform Windows that this region should not be protected with DEP (which it will be on processors which support NX bits).

More information can be found here: [Windows ISV Security.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx) Note that you will need to call your function through a pointer in all cases. If your code is not modifying at first, you can initialize the pointer to a code section at startup.